# Non-fixed height of graph (amCharts)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, amcharts

I'm trying to use amCharts for creating a graph.
Now my html contains following:

```
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```

It fills all screen by width, but there is hardcoded height. As a result it displays incorrectly on my phone. When I try this:

```
height: 50%;
```

It doesn't work (nothing shows).

Is it possible to set height in percents?(I need a graph which will occupy 50% of the screen's height). Maybe it's possible to implement this through Bootstrap (how)?

Comment: Can we have a jsfiddle please ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/puvmm5d0/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you don't specify the height of your page.
The width works, because your browser will use your display width as 100% reference. The height reference, however, is the the height of the content, which is zero in this case.

To solve this just add this to your css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjdywsuz/).